# How to solve $x^4-2x^3-x^2+2x+1=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quartics

How to solve $x^4-2x^3-x^2+2x+1=0$?

Answer given is: $$\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$$

I tried solving it by taking common factors:

$$x^3(x-2)-x(x-2)+1=0  $$ $$x(x-2)(x^2-1)+1=0   $$ $$(x+1)(x)(x-1)(x-2)+1=0$$

But it's not leading me anywhere.

Comment: Try $f=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2863912/42969

Comment: @MartinR Thanks a lot. The link has helped.

Comment: There were some other beautiful answers below. They seem to have been deleted now. I wonder why. If you guys are reading, thank you for your answers. I wish your posts were not deleted. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quadratic substitution question: applying substitution $p=x+\frac1x$ to $2x^4+x^3-6x^2+x+2=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480102/quadratic-substitution-question-applying-substitution-p-x-frac1x-to-2x4x)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I made a solution.  Have you seen this somewhere before..?

Comment: @lonestudent, Please go through the links inside my post here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480102/quadratic-substitution-question-applying-substitution-p-x-frac1x-to-2x4x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

Let $x-2=p.$

Then you will have a perfect square. It comes from a general fact:

"One more than a product of four consecutive positive integers is a perfect square."

Please take a look at the following link:

[Prove that the product of four consecutive positive integers plus one is a perfect square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155040/prove-that-the-product-of-four-consecutive-positive-integers-plus-one-is-a-perfe)

Comment: Well this deserves a mention on the "surprising theorems" thread.

Comment: If $x-1=p$ then $x=p+1\implies$ my equation becomes $(p+2)(p+1)(p)(p-1)+1=0$. How would that lead to a perfect square?

Comment: Great. Multiply the middle two, and the first and last one.

Comment: One last step: Suppose  $y= p^2 +p.$ Then are done. Try and let me know.

Comment: Multiplying middle two, I get $p^2+p$. Multiplying last two, I get, $p^2+p-2$. So, maybe I can put $p^2+p=t$. So, I get $t(t-2)+1=0\implies t^2-2t+1=0$. I didn't understand your $y=p+1$ step.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Sorry to confuse you.

Comment: Congrats! You did it.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: Hello, Boka, I just figured we need not have substituted $p$. We could have just multiplied the middle two and the first and the last one in the original equation itself and then substituted $x^2-x$.

Comment: I said what thought instantly. Thanks for letting me know. It's basically the same thing.

Comment: I suggested that "p substitution" so that it becomes "more clear" that we have the pattern $p(p+1)(p+2)(p+3) +1$. Basically, I was familiar with the exact same expression. That's why I said that stupid p substitution. You're correct. That one is useless.

Comment: Got it. That $p$ substitution indeed helped me see that it's a product of four consecutive integers. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Another way to notice the factorization
$$x^4-2x^3-x^2+2x+1=0$$
Since $x=0$ is not the root of the equation, divide by $x^2$ to get
$$x^2 -2x-1 + \frac{2}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2} = 0$$
Rewrite it as
$$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2} - 2\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right) - 1 = 0$$
or
$$\left(x-\frac1x\right)^2 + 2 - 2\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right) - 1 = 0$$
Substitute $t = x - 1/x$
$$t^2 + 2 - 2t - 1 = 0\\
t^2 - 2t + 1 = 0 \\ (t-1)^2 = 0$$
Substitute back to get the final result
$$\left(x - \frac{1}{x} - 1\right)^2 = 0$$
which says
$$(x^2-x-1)^2 = 0$$

Comment: Thanks, it's quite a helpful method.

Answer (score 2):

#### General solution:

I will solve a specific quartic equation that is a specific case of a general quartic equation.

---

Let, $a≠0,~ b≠0$,  then we have

$$ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=0$$

$$x^2+\frac e{ax^2}+\frac ba x+\frac d{ax}+\frac ca=0$$

$$\begin{align}&x^2+\frac ea \times \frac 1{x^2}+\frac ba \left(x+\frac {d}{bx}\right)+\frac ca=0&\end{align}$$

This quartic equation can be directly converted to the quadratic equation in the case below, avoiding the cubic equation.

$$\begin{align}&x+\frac {d}{bx}=t \\
\implies &t^2=x^2+\frac{d^2}{b^2}\times \frac {1}{x^2}+\frac{2d}{b}\end{align}$$

Then, if $$\frac ea =\frac{d^2}{b^2}$$

We have

$$t^2-\frac{2d}{b}+\frac ba t+\frac ca=0$$

$$t^2+\frac ba t+\left(\frac ca-\frac{2d}{b}\right)=0$$

The last equation is a quadratic equation.

After solving quadratic, you wil get

$$x+\frac {d}{bx}=t$$

$$bx^2-btx+d=0$$

The last equation is also a quadratic equation.

---

In your case we have

$$a=1,b=-2,c=-1, d=2, e=1$$

This means

$$\frac ea =\frac{d^2}{b^2}$$

holds.

Comment: That's quite elaborative! +1

Answer (score 0):

$x^4-2x^3-x^2+2x+1 = 0$

You should split the middle terms and try to look for a common factor.

$x^4-x^3-x^2-x^3+x^2+x-x^2+x+1 = 0$

$x^2(x^2-x-1)-x(x^2-x-1)-1(x^2-x-1) = 0$

$(x^2-x-1)^2 = 0$

Take the square root:

$x^2-x-1 = ±0$

$x^2-x-1 = 0 \lor x^2-x-1 = -0$

Add $\frac{5}{4}$:

$x^2-x+\frac{1}{4} = \frac{5}{4} \lor x^2-x+\frac{1}{4} = \frac{5}{4}$

We have two identical quadratic equations so all roots will coincide and there will be two repeated roots instead of four distinct roots.

$(x-\frac{1}{2})^2 = \frac{5}{4}$

Take the square root:

$x-\frac{1}{2} = ±\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}$

$x-\frac{1}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{5}{4}} \lor x-\frac{1}{2} = -\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}$

Add $\frac{1}{2}$:

$x = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} \lor x = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

obten la raiz negativa de la siguiente funcion con 4 cifras decimales.

$2x^4-2x^3+x^2+3x-4=0 \quad\quad$ newton raphson

Comment: I think this answer would be better with more explanation. For instance, how did you obtain polynomial $2x^4-2x^3+x^2+3x-4\;$? - - - Welcome to Math Stack.